# Dates on ApplyFilter VBA Access

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, filter

Im trying to apply filter for a table, the filter will be after the date #01-01-2022# tan later I will export but when i tried to run the code doesn work. Any help pls

```
Function Filter()
DoCmd.OpenTable "RF", acViewNormal, acEdit
DoCmd.ApplyFilter Format("[Fecha envío]", "dd-mm-yyyy") & "<#" & Format(1 - 1 - 2022, "dd-mm-yyyy") & "#"
End Function
```

---Edit----

This is the example of the table i want to apply the filter

| Fecha envío (d-m-yyyy) |
| --- |
| 05-02-2018 |
| 01-04-2021 |
| 31-03-2022 |
| 23-03-2022 |

After some comments I did some modification to the code

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter Format([Fecha envío], "d-m-yyyy") > Format(#1/1/2022#, "d-m-yyyy")
```

2cond Edit

I solved thw filter with the following code

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Fecha envío]>=#" & Format(#1/1/2022#, "d-m-yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have a fundamental misunderstanding about what the [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) does, what kind of string [ApplyFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.applyfilter) expects and what the VBA expression `1-1-2022` means (hint: it evaluates to `-2022`, do you see why?). I suggest you read up on these topics, including the examples provided in the documentation. Otherwise, any help we provide will be in vain.

Comment: Oh, and [VBA date literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/date-data-type) don't have the format `#dd-mm-yyyy#`.

Comment: Short answer: [Turn dates to numbers instead](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/convert-date-to-number.278416/)

Comment: Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.applyfilter

Comment: At the very least you need to feed a string to the filter. Example: `Format([Fecha envío], "d-m-yyyy") & " > " & Format(#1/1/2022#, "d-m-yyyy")`

Comment: If dates are text, not actual date values, and they contain placeholder zeroes, then the criteria must also be formatted with placeholder zeros. `"dd-mm-yyyy"`. Simply saying "doesn't work" is not enough info - what happens: error message, wrong result, nothing?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to use for a fixed date:

```vb
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "[Fecha envío] < DateSerial(2022, 1, 1)"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "[Fecha envío]>=#" & Format(#1/1/2022#, "d-m-yyyy") & "#"
```